# Add text and hyperlink image to table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a table which has a cell with text and a small plus button. Onclicking the plus button, I want to display more rows corresponding to that entry.

How do I format the cell in this manner.

```
<td> text </td>
```

should also have an image that is a hyperlink or can invoke the onclick function

I am appending this cell to the table

```
 udate += "<td onClick=showRows('" + or +"')>"+ or + "</td>"
```

I want this cell to have an image as well apart from the or variable text

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You need a minimal example. This will require some javascript programming to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're after here but this should get you started. This approach is using JQuery to simply add a table cell dynamically when you click on the button.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
      $(this).parent('td').after('<td>test</td>');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```